# Non-linear graph getting from an experiment finding the enthalpy of vaporization of LN

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, experimental-physics

The experiment went as follows：
[image]

Liquid nitrogen (LN) was contained in the glass dewar. A controlled heat input to the liquid is supplied using a D.C. and the power is calculated from measurements of the current flowing in a resistor in the LN and the voltage developed across it. Flow rate and pressure are then measured by the gas flow meter and a pressure meter respectively, which are connected via 2 tubes to the glass dewar.

The equation can be derived as: 
$$ \frac{dE}{dt}=IU=\frac{m_mPL}{RT}\frac{dV}{dt}$$
$\frac{dE}{dt}$: electrical power; $I$: current; $U$: voltage; $m_m$: molar mass of LN; $P$: pressure; $R$: gas constant; $T$: temperature of LN; $\frac{dV}{dt}$: flow rate.

Since there was no way to measure $T$, I have to assume $T$ is constant at the boiling temperature ($77K$. (If not constant, how would I compute $L$ without measureing T?) Plotting $IU$ against $P\frac{dV}{dt}$ should yield a straight line. $L$ can then be determined from its slope. However, the 3 sets of results I did all give a curve relation, which all look like this:

[image]

The reduced $\chi ^2=1.91$ which means the fit is consistent. Why is this not a straight line? Using a linear fit would give a $\chi ^2$ of 5~10.

Alternatively, since $P$ is about a few hPa plus 1 atm, it's approximately constant. So plotting $IU$ against $\frac{dV}{dt}$ will give a graph like:

[image]

which still looks a bit curvy. What may the reasons?

Using the slope from a straight line fit, 
[image]

I get $L=\frac{mRT}{m_m}= 6540 J/kg$ and the specified value is $2790 J/kg$, which is inconsistent.

---

This is the data in excel I'm working on. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CiaP8lm-Gw89BigLBU5XIBdxXKRSnXMb

Comment: How certain are you of your assumption that T is constant at 77 K? If T increases with power, it would result in greater flow rate and that would explain your measurement. What would happen if you assumed the known value of L and tried to compute T - how does that look? Also - is your flow meter thermally compensated? What is its mechanism - would you trust it at these (reported) temperatures? Would its temperature drop with flow rate? Does that affect anything? Just trying to think aloud here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually I'm totally unsure if it's constant. But if not, how would I then compute L without knowing T? In working backwards I found T even decreases aymptotically with power (might be a mistake). The pipes are probably not thermally compensated. Sorry to ask but why should I consider the temperature of the gas flow meter? @Floris

Comment: Hi lkjhgtf. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.